# SQL: How to determine how long object in same location (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, location, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, latitude-longitude

I am trying to determine how long an object is in the same location, and what time it was first in that location for that duration.  If it leaves the location and comes back, I need another row with a new time calculation.

Data:

| ObjectID | DateTime | Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 38.09 | 20.99 |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | 30.34 |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | 30.34 |
| 23 | 5/3/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | 30.34 |
| 23 | 5/3/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | 30.34 |
| 23 | 5/3/2021 23:00 | 39.88 | 29.00 |
| 23 | 5/4/2021 12:00 | 39.88 | 29.00 |
| 23 | 5/4/2021 16:00 | 20.77 | 11.66 |
| 23 | 5/4/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | 30.34 |
| 23 | 5/5/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | 30.34 |
| 23 | 5/5/2021 16:00 | 20.77 | 11.66 |

Desired Results:

| ObjectID | StartTime | Lat | Lon | HoursInLocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | 30.34 | 24:00 |
| 23 | 5/3/2021 23:00 | 39.88 | 29.00 | 13:00 |
| 23 | 5/4/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | 30.34 | 13:00 |

My real data does not have a consistent DateTime frequency, I used it here to make it easier to read. Real data also has multiple ObjectID's.  Location of the object between entries is considered unknown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-island problem.  For this version, the difference of row numbers is probably the best solution:

```
select objectid, lat, lng, min(datetime), max(datetime),
       datediff(minute, min(datetime), max(datetime)) / 60.0 as hours_diff
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by objectid, lat, lng order by datetime) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (partition by objectid order by datetime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by objectid, lat, lng, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
having count(*) > 1;
```

This returns each period of time when an object is at a location.

Comment: This doesn't work when the object returns to the same location.  The query will return another row showing that the object was at 40.11/30.34 from 5/2/2021 16:00 until 5/5/2021 12:00.

Comment: It will also return that the object was at 20.77/11.66 from 5/4/2021 16:00 to 5/5/2021 16:00.

Comment: I believe the difference is that this solution is finding the difference in time between locations.
I need to find the difference in time between locations when it has not been in an other location in-between.

Comment: @CarFrogs . . . I fixed the query.